# How to get a specific selection from contenteditable

Tags: javascript, range, selection, contenteditable, caret

What I'm trying to do is to get a selection only for a word I want from contenteditable inputs. For example,

Hello My World

from the above input value, I want to select only the word 'My' and get the string value of it.

so far, I have written a function that gets a selection upto the caret from 0 range like so:

```
function selectUptoCaret(el){
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(el);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

    var sel = window.getSelection()
    sel.removeAllRanges()
    sel.addRange(preCaretRange)
  }
```

When I click 'y' from the word, 'My', it selects 'Hello My'.
but again, I only want to select 'My', not 'Hello My'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mostly there, but the problem you're getting of having everything to the left of the caret highlighted probably has to do with the fact you're not calling `preCaretRange.setStart()` and so it's thinking the start should be zero. I modified your function a little bit in order to get it to select the actual word your cursor is at:

```
function selectUptoCaret(el){
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();

    var startOffset = range.startContainer.textContent.lastIndexOf(' ', range.startOffset);
    var endOffset = range.endContainer.textContent.indexOf(' ', range.endOffset);

    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(el);
    preCaretRange.setStart(range.startContainer, ~startOffset ? startOffset + 1: 0);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, ~endOffset ? endOffset : range.endContainer.textContent.length);

    var sel = window.getSelection()
    sel.removeAllRanges()
    sel.addRange(preCaretRange)
}
```

My assumption is that the `el` param passed into `selectUptoCaret` is the actual contentEditable HTML element.

My changes were:

- take the cursor position and get the position of the next and previous spaces
- if there is no previous space (determined by the `~startOffset` check) we will start at 0 because we are in the first word
- if there is no following space (determined by the `~endOffset` check) we will use the full length of the text content because we are in the last word.
- set the `setStart` on our `preCaretRange` object to make sure we have a finite start point that is not necessarily the beginning of the text content

Note: my ternary `~startOffset ? startOffset + 1 : 0` is equivalent to saying `startOffset > -1 ? startOffset + 1 : 0`. Using the `~` bitwise operator is a convenient way of checking that a value is not `-1` (since `~ -1 === 0`).

This now will only select the current word at your caret's position.